# Why does passing '1.0' to a function change it to '1' in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Can someone explain to me why when pass 1.0 to a function in javascript it gets converted to 1 and how to work around this quirk?

```
var return_me = function(value) {
    return value;
}

console.log("1.0 is returned as " + return_me(1.0));
```

Comment: It's not converted to 1, 1.0 is exactly equal to 1. Why is this a problem?

Comment: That is how JavaScript numbers work, but in your example it should be 1.0 since it is a string and not a number.

Comment: In Chrome output is '1.0 is returned as 1.0'

Comment: Because in this example he actually passed a string

Comment: Actually it only converts '1.0' to 1 if you process the string as a number if you do nothing to it like my script above it stays a string. However if I pass 1.0 instead of '1.0' it converts it returns 1

Comment: If you want to understand why numbers in JS act funny, read up: http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html

Comment: That doesn't discuss this issue beyond the fact that 1 and 1.0 are both floats in javascript.

Comment: Because they're both floats (indeed js only have floats) they're both the same number. Internally they're represented by the same value: 0x3f800000. That is to say, 1 is 0x3f800000 and 1.0 is 0x3f800000. So when you print it back out, js cannot distinguish between the two and just print 1 because that's how the printing/stringifying algorithm works in js. But I must strongly stress, this is only an artifact of forcing the language to print it out. Internally 1 and 1.0 are the same number - there is no conversion.

Comment: Note to pedants: yeah, I know, js uses doubles and not floats. But that doesn't change the core of the reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript there are six build in types of values.

1. string
2. number
3. boolean
4. null and undefined
5. object
6. symbol

These are mentioned to the book [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20&%20going/ch2.md) which I find really useful in my effort to learn javascript.

As a result js sees the var value of your function as a typeof number and understands that 1.0 is the same as 1. (in case the 1.0 was 1.9 it returns 1.9 as expected).

Now if you want to keep these decimals (even if there are zero digits) you could pass the value as a string.

```
console.log("1.0 is returned as " + return_me("1.0"));
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't distinguish between `int` or `float` like other more strongly typed languages. It just has one `Number` type. From the [ECMA specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3):

> Once the exact mathematical value (MV) for a numeric literal has been determined, it is
>   then rounded to a value of the Number type. If the MV is 0, then the
>   rounded value is +0; otherwise, the rounded value must be the Number
>   value for the MV (as specified in 8.5), unless the literal is a
>   DecimalLiteral and the literal has more than 20 significant digits, in
>   which case the Number value may be either the Number value for the MV
>   of a literal produced by replacing each significant digit after the
>   20th with a 0 digit or the Number value for the MV of a literal
>   produced by replacing each significant digit after the 20th with a 0
>   digit and then incrementing the literal at the 20th significant digit
>   position. A digit is significant if it is not part of an ExponentPart
>   and
>
> - it is not 0;
> - or there is a nonzero digit to its left and there is a nonzero digit, not in the ExponentPart, to its right.
>
> A conforming
>   implementation, when processing strict mode code (see 10.1.1), must
>   not extend the syntax of NumericLiteral to include OctalIntegerLiteral
>   as described in B.1.1.

[More info on `Number`.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)

So basically, the answer is that JavaScript will display numbers that look like integers as integers and numbers that look like floats as floats.